# Xamarin.iOS \ Visual Studio monotouch.dll error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run some source code that I downloaded from a tutorial

This is essentially an app that will allow users to manage contacts and calendar appointments etc.

I am very new to Xamarin & app development and I just wanted to run this because it is a very similar project to one that I am creating.

I have 1 error that is preventing me from running this app in debug mode...

"Cannot reference 'monotouch.dll' in a Xamarin.iOS project - it is implicitly reference by 'BTProgressHUD, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I cannot find 'monotouch.dll' anywhere in the project references.

At a guess I would say the 'monotouch.dll' reference in 'Xamarin.iOS' and 'BTProgressHUD' are conflicting but i cant work out what is going on.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: monotouch is the older 32 bit version - Xamarin.iOS is the new 32/64 version.  It sounds like you are using an older version of BTProgressHUD that only supports the old version

Comment: I am using version 1.20 of BTProgressHUD